# Windows Mobile Wi-Fi works for IE but not my app (SocketException)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, wifi, socketexception

I've been trying to add Wi-Fi connectivity to my Windows Mobile 6.1 .NET CE 3.5 application but can't figure out why I get the following SocketException:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectNoCheck(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Connection.doConnect(IPEndPoint ep)
   at System.Net.Connection.connect(Object ignored)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

ErrorCode 10060 (ConnectionTimedOut)

despite IE having perfect connectivity. Both IE and my application work fine over the cradle and GPRS connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a proxy server set in your connection manager?

Comment: I haven't got a proxy server set up, no.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the same server/resource in your code as in IE?

Comment: That's a very good point - that was my problem exactly, I was trying to connect to the wrong resource because I'd built my app with the wrong config file. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting to the same server/resource in your code as in IE.

Retroactive answers are fun.